# How to allow virtual host in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have upgraded my Apache to 2.4 and all my virtual hosts configs stopped to work. Most of the were configured like following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin MYEMAIL
    DocumentRoot "MYPATH"
    ServerName MYNAME
    ErrorLog "logs/garmonia3.log"
    CustomLog "logs/garmonia3.log" common
    DirectoryIndex page.php
</VirtualHost>
```

First sites became forbidden. I tried to find some workarounds and found them like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin MYEMAIL
    DocumentRoot "MYPATH"
    ServerName MYNAME
    ErrorLog "logs/garmonia3.log"
    CustomLog "logs/garmonia3.log" common
    DirectoryIndex page.php
<Directory "MYDIR">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but these are probably obsolete, since Apache is swearing on both `Order` and `Allow` directory.

So how to enable?

Comment: Post the error message and post the full virtualhost without redacting things.

Comment: Did you read the upgrading advices? Sounds like exactly your problem is mentioned there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html